# Can someone explain how to connect to Azure SQL server using active directory password in robot framework

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, robotframework

Our database is Azure SQL server using active directory password. I am getting error using "connect to database pyodbc/pymssql" methods.

```
Connect to database pyodbc
```

```
Connect to database pymssql
```

Both didn't worked and was getting error.

I believe this active directory password is tricky and that's y the above methods didn't work. Can someone help

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to connect to Azure SQL using Pyodbc with Active Directory password using the code below:

```
import pyodbc
 
username = "ADuserName"
password = "ADpassword"
host = "<serverName>.database.windows.net"
database = "<databaseName>"
authentication = "ActiveDirectoryPassword"
driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
conn_string = (
     f'DRIVER={driver};'
    f'SERVER={host};'
    f'DATABASE={database};'
    f'UID={username};'
    f'PWD={password};'
    f'Authentication={authentication};' 
 )
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT @@version')
for row in cursor:
   print(row)
```

I got the error below:

[image]

As per [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-entra-azure-ad-blog/raising-the-baseline-security-for-all-organizations-in-the-world/ba-p/3299048), MFA is the default method of login for all Azure tenants. Hence, in the above code, I used `ActiveDirectoryInteractive` instead of `ActiveDirectoryPassword` to conform to MFA standards.

Here is the code to connect to the Azure SQL server with Active Directory authentication:

```
import pyodbc

username = "ADuserName"
host = "<serverName>.database.windows.net"
authentication = "ActiveDirectoryInteractive"
driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
conn_string = (
     f'DRIVER={driver};'
    f'SERVER={host};'
    f'DATABASE={database};'
    f'UID={username};'
    f'Authentication={authentication};' 
 )
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT @@version')
for row in cursor:
   print(row)
```

It will give a popup notification to enter the password of AD for authentication. After that, it connected to the Azure SQL database successfully without any error. Once we authenticate with this method, there is no need to provide a password while connecting to the server. It will connect automatically once authenticated, as shown below:

[image]